# Run dash application with main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a dash application(.py) with running code which looks like,

```
# whatever.py

from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = Dash()

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})
fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Global Apps'),
    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for your data.
    '''),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I execute this using `HOST=<xxxx> PORT=<xxxx> python -m whatever`

I would like to eliminate the if segment from the .py file while still running the dash server serving traffic

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I am willing to write another python wrapper file, or execute anything via command line.

**Please note**: I am not flexible with whatever.py and can't make any changes to that except abstracting away the two line segment.

One option to abstract away the if segment that comes to mind is by appending this segment to the .py file on the fly. We can do this during execution via command line, but that doesn't seem very stable or reliable.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is creating a new Python script just for running the server, named `runner.py`. In this file, you'd have to import your `app` object from the dash application file (Since you haven't supplied the file name of your dash application, I'll assume it's `dash_application.py` for demonstration purposes).

In `runner.py`:

```py
from dash_application import app
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Now you can remove the `if __name__ == "__main__":` segment from your dash application file, and run your app via the command line:

```bash
$ python3 runner.py
```

Comment: Thanks schlopp, it sounds right. However I did not mention, this app keyword could be anything. I am supplying a notepad for someone to write some dash code. Once they hit execute, I should be able to run this code. Now they might call their 'app' with any keyword.

Comment: I see. This will make things a little more complicated. I think your approach should be to loop through the variables of the file (`vars()` should do the trick), find one of the type `Dash` and do run_server on it.